"BufferQueueProducer: [test_1_0#0](id:166000000f8,api:1,p:18032,c:358)queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned" in android
In the scenario, when I create a new Surface Control, create a new Surface, attach it as a child to the root surface, and release Surface Control and Surface after separating it into repare. Then, the following problem occurred. If you know the cause or solution, please let me know. Thank you
04-19 17:15:57.546   302 18730 E VideoTunnelDisplay: [No-89](0xf0dc05b0) DequeueBuffer meson_vt_dequeue_buffer failed with -1,metafd:-1 need deq again,mDeQueuedErrCount:1
04-19 17:15:57.546   358  1072 E BufferQueueProducer: [test_1_0#0](id:166000000f8,api:1,p:18032,c:358) queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 E VideodecNonTunnelWrapper: [No-89](0xeae05e50) DequeueSurfaceBuffer DequeueBuffer failed
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 E VideoTunnelDisplay: [No-89](0xf0dc05b0) DequeueBuffer meson_vt_dequeue_buffer failed with -1,metafd:-1 need deq again,mDeQueuedErrCount:2
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 E VideodecNonTunnelWrapper: [No-89](0xeae05e50) DequeueSurfaceBuffer DequeueBuffer failed
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 E VideoTunnelDisplay: [No-89](0xf0dc05b0) DequeueBuffer meson_vt_dequeue_buffer failed with -1,metafd:-1 need deq again,mDeQueuedErrCount:3
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 E VideodecNonTunnelWrapper: [No-89](0xeae05e50) DequeueSurfaceBuffer DequeueBuffer failed
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 I VideodecNonTunnelWrapper: [No-89](0xeae05e50) TSP_onMessageReceived kWhatFlush vpid:2375
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 I VideodecNonTunnelWrapper: [No-89](0xeae05e50) OnFlush 
04-19 17:15:57.549 18032 18183 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
04-19 17:15:57.549   302 18730 I AmVideoDec: [0] "flush\n"
04-19 17:15:57.549 18032 18183 E FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
04-19 17:15:57.550 18032 18183 F OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering

